# How to use Selenium Webdriver to locate particular element in table

Tags: class, selenium, xpath, html-table, webdriver

[image]

The Table has many rows all with the same "action" label, and same classname for each row also.

I want to locate a particular row (please note I am dealing with a table that changes as information is added to it through the web UI.

Can anyone help?

I am using Selenium2Library. Attempting to automate on Firefox browser.
I want to identify the "action" if it matches with the data-id that I have stored as a variable.

When I copy the xpath it seems to be the same for all rows, also I do not want to identify according to the row as the rows can change.

Comment: How do you want to locate the particular row? Do you mean based on the user, the email, something else? Also, you should specify what language you are working in since selenium supports quite a few (ruby, java, etc).

Comment: Please note: i have added my reply above in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to locate it using the following css-selector:

```
a[data-id="6766"]
```

Or the following xpath:

```
//a[@data-id="6766"]
```

You could substitute the "6766" with your variable.

Comment: The above does not work, selenium is not able to find the element

Comment: If it doesn't work, then it is because the data id is randomly generated.  You need to find a different way to select the element.  If there are many rows in the table, how do you know which one you want?

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, on the second run of the test Selenium has correctly identified the element. Thank you for your help, much appreciated

Comment: That still indicates the ID is uniquely generated. Your tests should be passing every single time. Read what @MrTi is saying.